# Convert given array to object array using loops

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

My task was to convert array to object using loops.

```
arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
```

to object array

```
arr = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5};
```

I got the right result, but I am not sure about the way I was solving this task. 
Please give me a piece of advice.

```js
let arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
let obj = {};
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  obj[arr[i]] = i + 1
}

console.log(obj)
```

As I mentioned before, the result is right

```
{ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4, e: 5 }
```

But I tend to feel that there is a better solution.

Comment: If your task was to create an object from an array using a loop that's a good solution.

Comment: The answer depends on how you want to handle edge cases like arrays with holes `['a', 'b',,,,,,,'c']` or with duplicate elements `['a', 'b', 'a', 'c']`

Answer (score 0):

One option is to transform the `arr` into an array of entries, using the index to specify the value, then use `Object.fromEntries` to turn it into an object:

```js
let arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
const obj = Object.fromEntries(
  arr.map((prop, i) => [prop, i + 1])
);
console.log(obj);
```

(though, `Object.fromEntries` is a relatively new method)

Comment: Can that be considered "using loops"?

Comment: *Anything* involving iteration uses a loop somewhere, though OP can clarify if he doesn't want to use functional methods

Comment: They probably won't know not to exclude functional methods because I doubt they're that far into the course(?) to know what they are. A "loop" has a very specific meaning at that early stage.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a `while` statement and increment `i` only once.

```js
var array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
    object = {},
    i = 0;

while (i < array.length) object[array[i]] = ++i;

console.log(object);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to accomplish this.

1. Initially set the accumulator to an empty object `{}`
2. For each iteration use [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) on the accumulator in a new object
3. Then add a new property to this new object which will be your `currrent` and set the value to `i` (the current index) + 1.
4. Return the new accumulator
5. Repeat till end of the list

```js
const arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];

const res = arr.reduce((acc,cur,i)=>({...acc, [cur]:i+1}), {});

console.log(res);
```

Verbose solution without spread operator:

```js
const arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];

const res = arr.reduce((acc,cur,i)=>{
  acc[cur] = i + 1;
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(res);
```